# How to get predictions with multiple outcomes with knn model using tidymodels?

Tags: r, tidyverse, knn, predict, tidymodels

Update: [cross-posted to RStudio Community](https://community.rstudio.com/t/how-to-get-predictions-with-multiple-outcomes-with-knn-model-using-tidymodels/86427) after more than a day with no activity. I will post any answers here.

I would like to use knn regression to predict multiple outcomes, but I get a single output variable. Here's a reprex:

```
library(tidymodels)

y1 <- rnorm(100, 5)
y2 <- rnorm(100, 6)
y3 <- rnorm(100, 7)

x1 <- rnorm(100, 8)
x2 <- rnorm(100, 12)
x3 <- rnorm(100, 6)

dat <- tibble(y1, y2, y3, x1, x2, x3)

data_split <- initial_split(dat)

train_data <- training(data_split)

form <- formula(y1 + y2 + y3 ~ x1 + x2 + x3)

rec <- recipe(form, data = dat) %>% 
  step_normalize(all_predictors()) %>% 
  prep()

model <-
  nearest_neighbor() %>%
  set_engine("kknn") %>%
  set_mode("regression") %>%
  set_args(dist_power = 2, neighbors = 5)


wflow <- workflow() %>% 
  add_model(model) %>% 
  add_recipe(rec)

fit1 <- fit(wflow, train_data)

predict(fit1, new_data = testing(data_split))
```

I was attempting to predict y1, y2, y3 rather than a single output. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

[Here is the thread from RStudio Community discussion](https://community.rstudio.com/t/how-to-get-predictions-with-multiple-outcomes-with-knn-model-using-tidymodels/86427).

Answer from [Max Kuhn](https://twitter.com/topepos):

It depends on the underlying model. parsnip supports multivariate models but tune and other packages do not (yet, at least).

Here's an example:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(tidymodels)
#> ── Attaching packages ────────────────────────────────────── tidymodels 0.1.1 ──
#> ✓ broom     0.7.0           ✓ recipes   0.1.14.9000
#> ✓ dials     0.0.9           ✓ rsample   0.0.8.9000 
#> ✓ infer     0.5.2           ✓ tune      0.1.1.9001 
#> ✓ modeldata 0.1.0           ✓ workflows 0.2.1      
#> ✓ parsnip   0.1.3.9000      ✓ yardstick 0.0.7
#> ── Conflicts ───────────────────────────────────────── tidymodels_conflicts() ──
#> x scales::discard() masks purrr::discard()
#> x dplyr::filter()   masks stats::filter()
#> x recipes::fixed()  masks stringr::fixed()
#> x dplyr::lag()      masks stats::lag()
#> x yardstick::spec() masks readr::spec()
#> x recipes::step()   masks stats::step()

y1 <- rnorm(100, 5)
y2 <- rnorm(100, 6)
y3 <- rnorm(100, 7)

x1 <- rnorm(100, 8)
x2 <- rnorm(100, 12)
x3 <- rnorm(100, 6)

dat <- tibble(y1, y2, y3, x1, x2, x3)

data_split <- initial_split(dat)

train_data <- training(data_split)

form <- formula(y1 + y2 + y3 ~ x1 + x2 + x3)

rec <- recipe(form, data = dat) %>% 
   step_normalize(all_predictors()) %>% 
   prep()

model <-
   linear_reg() %>%
   set_engine("lm") %>%
   set_mode("regression") 


wflow <- workflow() %>% 
   add_model(model) %>% 
   add_recipe(rec)

fit1 <- fit(wflow, train_data)

predict(fit1, new_data = testing(data_split))
#> # A tibble: 25 x 3
#>    .pred_y1 .pred_y2 .pred_y3
#>       <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>
#>  1     4.95     6.02     6.88
#>  2     5.02     5.87     6.87
#>  3     4.55     5.78     7.29
#>  4     5.04     6.23     7.13
#>  5     5.30     5.94     6.89
#>  6     5.15     6.11     6.76
#>  7     5.32     5.87     7.21
#>  8     4.89     5.91     7.22
#>  9     4.75     6.26     6.83
#> 10     4.90     6.03     6.70
#> # … with 15 more rows
```

Created on 2020-10-30 by the reprex package (v0.3.0)